# One Node Restful service that connects to thousands of Mongo Databases?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a Restful service application that uses MongoDb and I need that service to change the connected mongo database based on a parameter. 
I expect to need a very large number of databases. Maybe thousands..
I tried to use Mongoose but it allows only one connection.
What is the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to connect to so many different databases? This is an unusual way to use namespaces in MongoDB.

Comment: I'm building a cms for websites. Every website will have its own database (pages, page content, admins, newsletters...etc). I want to develop a single web service that takes care of all the websites database(s) queries..

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's reasonable to organize by site in multiple databases rather than by object type in multiple collections, I suppose. Drivers should be able to handle multiple databases just by making multiple connection/client objects, or by working through one connection but talking to multiple databases. Mongoose doesn't talk to more than one database with one connection, but you can create multiple connections. See the ["Multiple connections"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) section in the docs. Also, if you have squillions of databases, read over the [namespace size limits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have read the 'Multiple Connections' part of the documentation before. In my case it will not help much because I have to hard-code all the databases in the connection. 
Not a good solution when I have 1000 Databases :)..
The perfect solution would be connecting to the server then choosing which database to use through (use <database>) but I didn't find that command in mongoose..
I also know about the 24,000 namespaces limit. That's another reason why I need a separate database for each website..

Comment: Yes, then from what I know of Mongoose (which is far from everything), it is not a good choice here. You may want to use the straight Node.js driver.